# Как выбрать первую ячейку в строке?

Tags: jquery

я то думал - $(tr td:first)...
Но нет, срабатывает для первой строки только.
Кто-нибудь знает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так выберет все первые ячейки

```
$('tr td:first-child')
```

А вот так выбрет просто самый первый td

```
$('tr td:first')
```

Смотрим - http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/trsyj/

Comment: @Spectre, а кто ж мешает [создать свой селектор](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_jQuery)

Comment: на самом деле я чушь сморозил: [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: $('tr td:first-child') почему-то выделяет ВСЕ ячейки в строке. Я сам в шоке.

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov, покажите свой код

Comment: видимо, если ошибка и есть, то н в этом участке кода. $('tr td:first-child') работает нормально. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте тогда так:

`$(function(){
   $('td').eq(0);
});`

Мой пример для наглядности [выбор ТОЛЬКО первой ячейки](http://jsfiddle.net/LeD4eG/XbHb4/)

Comment: Эквивалентно `$('tr td:first')`

Comment: Да, спасибо, но это немножко не то.

Comment: ну в вашем случае сработает для td, которые находятся вне tr, что маловероятно

Comment: Я и не претендовал на точность изложения. это общий пример, на основании которого можно создать более узконаправленный селектор.